# Magento 2: Check condition on Click of "Proceed to Checkout"

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, custom

May be I need to create Event Observer. I would like to check Product's Type Condition & Display Message Accordingly on Shopping Cart Page.

```
  <event name="controller_action_predispatch_XXX_XX_XX">
  <observer name="checkcout_page" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\CheckShoppingCartObserver" />
  </event>
```

http://www.advancedcheckout.com/blog/list-event-magento2.html/

https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/

It's not giving event information when it's gonna execute on, on which place/page?

What will be method i need use instead of XXX.

Comment: for which event want to fire? after click on checkout button?

Comment: Need to check Before Event while click on "Checkout" Button. Can?

Comment: you can try with controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index event

Comment: @Rakesh ok let me check that

Comment: @Rakesh It works :). Must say Excellent Knowledge you have. I'm just a beginner. There will be no case like `pre` & `post` dispatch right?

Comment: you can use controller_action_predispatch__ and controller_action_postdispatch_ action event

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to just use  **controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index** action to check before checkout index  page is load.

```
 <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index">
    <observer name="checkcout_page" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\CheckShoppingCartObserver" />
 </event>
```

If you want to fire event before any action is called you have to use **controller_action_predispatch_XX_XX_XX**

If you want to fire event after any action is called you have to use action event **controller_action_postdispatch_XX_XX_XX**

In above section **XX_XX_XX** is handlename/action of page.
You can call any action in pre and post dispatch event for each page.

In your case **checkout_index_index** handler is used.

Just for example, 
If you want to do something before checkout cart page is load you have to use event **controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index**

If you want to do something after checkout cart page is loaded, you need to define **controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_index** action and set your logic in observer file.

Comment: hi bro it was working fine but now proceed to checkout is not proceeding on next page ..

Comment: Hi Rakesh Jesadiya.How to get estimate shipping details from controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index event?